# Convert a string with letters and numbers to a float (price in list with other things too)

Tags: python, string, integer, int

I am having an issue with my code what I would like to do is convert a string from a list into a float so I can do maths with those numbers. (This is in Python 3). For example,

```
price = float(line[i+1])
```

With i+1 being:

```
Price: £139.99
```

What I want my result to be is,

```
price = 139.99
```

Thanks!

EDIT: Price: 139.99 is an example, its sometimes other ones such as Price: 54.99

EDIT: List is

```
GTIN-8 Code: 12345670
Product name: Razer Blackwidow Chroma
Product price: £139.99
Product amount: 1
GTIN-8 Code: 44444440
Product name: Razer Deathadder Chroma
Product price: £54.99
Product amount: 1
GTIN-8 Code: 66666660
Product name: Paper
Product price: £0.99
Product amount: 100
GTIN-8 Code: 77777770
Product name: Steelseries QCK+ Heavy Mousepad
Product price: £19.99
Product amount: 1
```

So with the list above if someone put in 12345670, it would go down two lines to the price line, with that line I want to take everything away but the numbers so I can add them to the total price each time someone enters a product.

EDIT: The function, not properly indented because paste  problems.

```
def barcode()
    choice = input("GTIN-8 ")
    quantity = input("How many? ")
    f = open("Items.txt", 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i in range(0,len(lines)):
    line = lines[i]
    if choice in (line):
    f = open("Result.txt", 'a')
    f.write(lines[i+1])
    f.write(lines[i+2])
    f.write("Num: " + quantity + "\n")
    f.write("\n")
    text = (lines[i+2])
    price = float(line.split("£")[1])
    amount = (quantity * price)
    total += (amount)
    anything_else = input("Any more?")
    if anything_else == 'y':
        f.close()
        barcode()
   else:
       f.close()
      what_to_do()
    break
```

Comment: `text = "Price: £139.99"` so `price = float(text[8:])`

Comment: I researched a bit and tried the general ways of converting to float but they didnt work. Im new to python

Comment: @furas lets use `float` and not `int`. Ideally, he should be using `decimal.Decimal`

Comment: @AyushShanker right, it has to be float :)

Comment: Read edit please, i didnt explain properly

Comment: `if text[7] in '£$': price = float(text[8:]) else: price = float(text[7:])`

Comment: Can you explain what that means @furas I don't understand it. Thanks :)

Comment: which part don't you understand ? `text[7]` ? `text[8:]` ? use `print(text[7], text[8:])` to see what it gives.

Comment: What does the [8: ] and [7: ] mean?

Comment: it slicing `[start:end]` - it gets part of text or list from `start` element ot the `end-1` element -  if you skip `start` then it starts at first (0) element, if you skip `end` it get all to the last element.

Comment: https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/python3/

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'price: £139.99\n'

Comment: Edited the post with more information of what I'm trying to do, please take a look.

Comment: The code in your for loop needs indented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the string at `£` and convert the second substring to a float

For example:

```
line = "Price: £5000.8"
price = float(line.split("£")[1]) # in your case line => line[i+1]
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT:

Changed after question edit.
You could try this:

```
def barcode():
    print("\n" + "Amazon")
    choice = input("GTIN-8 ")
    quantity = input("How many? ")
    f = open("Items.txt", 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i in range(0, len(lines)):
        line = lines[i]
        if choice in (line):
            f = open("Result.txt", 'a')
        f.write(lines[i + 1])
        f.write(lines[i + 2])
        f.write("Num: " + quantity + "\n")
        f.write("\n")
        text = (lines[i + 2])
        price = float(text.split("£")[1])  # changed here
        amount = (quantity * price)
        total += (amount)
    anything_else = input("Any more?")
    if anything_else == 'y':
        f.close()
        barcode()
    else:
        f.close()
        what_to_do()
        break
```

Comment: Error: list index out of range

Comment: can you give me some **exact** examples of the strings inside the line list.
for example: `line[0] = "Price: £88.99"` `line[1] = "Price: £100.99"` ... and so on

Comment: GTIN-8 Code: 12345670Product name: Razer Blackwidow ChromaProduct price: £139.99Product amount: 1GTIN-8 Code: 44444440Product name: Razer Deathadder ChromaProduct price: £54.99Product amount: 1GTIN-8 Code: 66666660Product name: PaperProduct price: £0.99Product amount: 100GTIN-8 Code: 77777770Product name: Steelseries QCK+ Heavy MousepadProduct price: £19.99Product amount: 1

Comment: I cant split it, everytime I press enter it sends.

Comment: do you have all the product price in a separate list or in a variable. Your question was to convert 'Price: £99.00' with various amounts. If you do not have the price in a separate list or variables, you should change the question to include that as well. If you do have the price string separately, tell me the list contents as `line[0] = "'Price: £99.00"` and so on.

Comment: They are all together, prices & everything else.

Comment: The lines depend on what the user inputs, my program searches for that line and goes two lines ahead to get the line with the price

Comment: So with the list above if someone put in 12345670, it would go down two lines to the price line, with that line I want to take everything away but the numbers so I can add them to the total price each time someone enters a product.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share the full code along with one sample input? Thanks.

Comment: I cant share the full code (school) but I can probably share the function.

Comment: Yeah that works! Add it to your initial question with a sample input and expected value of the print function.

Comment: Edited my answer, if it helps, do mark as answer. Otherwise, let me know here, thanks!

Comment: Need to indent the for loop

Comment: Another Error now. TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: It's a problem with line "amount = (quantity * price)"

Comment: You will have to typecast your quantity to `int` explicitly. Try this replace `quantity = input("How many? ")` with `quantity = int(input("How many? "))`

Comment: That fixed that, but now there is another error. UnboundLocalError: local variable 'total' referenced before assignment

Comment: You have not declared the variable `total`. You can declare it globally outside your function as `total=0`. Any other error's are outside the scope of this question, post a new question if you have any more errors.